# Oracle Database 12c: How to also get the result index from a contains search

Tags: java, regex, database, oracle

I have a web service in Java that performs searches on an Oracle 12c Database. The problem is I have a `CONTAINS()` search:

```
String query = "select * from sys.my_table WHERE CONTAINS(my_clob_field, '" + searchString + "', 1) > 0";
```

but I also want to get the index(es) of the search word or phrase within the results.

Currently what I've tried is to take each of the returned search results and go through them performing a **REGEX** search in Java to find the start and stop indexes needed to highlight the search result on the front end.

This works fine for regular text but if the requirement is that the user can search for *any random arrangement of any characters* (i.e. #<@(F#><)$*>/\./#&!)#}{}][s fdf) the Java search needs to also find that exact string and return the start and stop index.

I escape out any special characters for the Oracle search, but an entirely different set of rules is needed for the Java search to find the index. Trying to get them to match up has turned out to be a nightmare and typically the Java **REGEX** search doesn't find the same occurrences that the Oracle Database search finds. I believe the approach I'm taking is totally wrong and there should be some simple way to also get the indexes of the occurrences of hte search word (or phrase).

**TL;DR:
When performing a `CONTAINS()` search, how could I *also* find the indexes of the search word or phrase within the returned search results using only an Oracle Database query (so I don't have to worry about losing search results to a REGEX mismatch)?**

Comment: `sys.my_table`??? Do ***not*** create your own tables in the `SYS` tablespace. Just don't. And do not use `SYS` or `SYSTEM` for regular work. Create a normal user and put your application data into the `USERS` tablespace (or create a new one). But do **not** use the system account or tablespaces for your application data.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for something like [REGEXP_INSTR()](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions162.htm#SQLRF06300)?  It will return zero if no match, otherwise returns the position of the first character of (or the first character following) the matching substring.

```
select 
  mytab.*,
  regexp_substr(my_clob_field, searchString),
  regexp_instr(my_clob_field, searchString)
from sys.my_table mytab
WHERE CONTAINS(my_clob_field, '" + searchString + "', 1) > 0
```

Comment: That looks promising. What if there are multiple occurrences of the search string in the CLOB field? From the query, I need the text from the CLOB field (which I was already getting) and also the indexes of each search string occurrence. Can you provide an implementation example? Would there need to be two queries, one to get the CLOB field text (using CONTAINS()), and another to get the indexes?

Comment: If there are potentially several matches in the search string, you are probably better off writing a PL/SQL procedure to do this repeated matching.  As for returning the first match and its index, you can do it in one query, I will post an example in my answer above.

Comment: I'm getting "from keyword not found where expected" error when using this the Java implementation of your query: `String query = "select *, regexp_substr(my_clob_field, '" + searchString + "'), regexp_instr(my_clob_field, '" + searchString + "') from sys.my_table WHERE CONTAINS(my_clob_field, '" + searchString + "', 1) > 0";`

Comment: Ahh, sorry, forgot you need a table alias if using * with other fields.  Answer update to include the alias.

Comment: Now is says `"MYTAB" invalid identifier`.

Comment: Did you add the alias in both places I added it?

Comment: `regexp_substr(my_clob_field, searchString),` always returns nothing and `regexp_instr(my_clob_field, searchString)` always returns 0. In the meantime, the CONTAINS() part of the query returns results as expected. All three use the same searchString.

Comment: At this point it would help to see the actual text and searchString.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97024/discussion-between-aaron-world-traveler-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but combining regexp_instr, and regexp_count as well as CONNECT BY LEVEL, I think you can get what you're looking for:

```
with base_qry as
(
     select 'ABCDABCDABCDEFGAB' as the_text from dual union all
     select '123456890AB' as the_text from dual union all
     select 'QCQC12345654321QCQC' as the_text from dual
), levels as
(
  SELECT LEVEL AS lvl
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY LEVEL <= ( SELECT MAX( regexp_count(the_text, :search_parm) ) FROM base_qry )
)
select the_text, :search_parm, REGEXP_INSTR(the_text, :search_parm, 1, lvl) as start_pos
from base_qry inner join
     levels on (lvl <= regexp_count(the_text, :search_parm))
order by 1, 3
```

Results (input AB):

```
THE_TEXT            :SEARCH_PARM    START_POS
123456890AB         AB              10
ABCDABCDABCDEFGAB   AB              1
ABCDABCDABCDEFGAB   AB              5
ABCDABCDABCDEFGAB   AB              9
ABCDABCDABCDEFGAB   AB              16
```